# Relaciones de muchos a muchos con una tabla tercera

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent

Buenas estoy realizando una `API` con `LARAVEL 5.1` , tengo estas relaciones:

```
alumnos
 -id
 -nombre

alumno_requisitos
 -id
 -alumno_id
 -requisito_id
 -codigoMatricula

archivos_alumnos
 -id
 -alumno_requisito_id
 -estado_archivo_id

estados_archivos
 -id
 -nombre
*requisitos
 -id
 -nombre
```

MODELOS.

```
    class Alumno extends Model
{
    //
    protected $casts = [
        "estado" => "boolean",
        "grado_alumno" => "boolean",
    ];
    public function serviciosSolicitados()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(ServicioSolicitado::class);
    }
    public function persona()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Persona::class);
    }
    public function requisitos()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Requisito::class, "alumno_requisitos", "alumno_id", "requisito_id")->withPivot("codigoMatricula", "fechaRegistro");
    }
}
```

*AlumnoRequisito

```
namespace App\Modules\BienestarUniversitario\Repository\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class AlumnoRequisito extends Model
{
    //
    protected $table = "alumno_requisitos";
    protected $fillable = ["codigoMatricula", "fechaRegistro"];
    public function archivos()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(ArchivoAlumnoRequisito::class);
    }

}
```

*ArchivoAlumnoRequisito

```
    <?php

namespace App\Modules\BienestarUniversitario\Repository\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class ArchivoAlumnoRequisito extends Model
{
    //
    protected $table = "archivo_alumno_requisitos";

    public function alumnoRequisito()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(alumnoRequisito::class);
    }
    public function estadoRequisito()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(EstadoArchivo::class, "estado_archivos_requisitos", "archivo_alumno_requisito_id", "estado_archivo_id");
    }
}
```

*EstadoArchivo

```
    <?php

namespace App\Modules\BienestarUniversitario\Repository\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class EstadoArchivo extends Model
{
    //
    protected $table = "estado_archivos";
    public function archivos()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(ArchivoAlumnoRequisito::class, "estado_archvos_requisitos", "estado_archivo_id", "archivo_alumno_requisito_id");
    }
}
```

Lo que quiero hacer es listar los requisitos de unu alumno con todo sus archivos y este que tenga su estado.